# How to get JTable selectedRow and selectedColumn during FocusLost event

Tags: java, jtable

Whenever there is a lostFocus inside a JTable, i need to capture the existing cell's row and column.

However, the condition below is always false because the source is always either a JTextField or a JComboBox.

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
int row, col;

Object source = e.getSource();
if(((Component) source).getParent() instanceof JTable_Ext){  //<-- always false
    table = (JTable_Ext) ((Component) source).getParent();
    row = table.getSelectedRow();
    col = table.getSelectedColumn();
}
```

To mitigate the above, i remember the row and col during FocusGained (as class level variable). The problem is, if the user click very fast all over the place within the JTable, somehow the row and column information will be out of sync.

Is there a way to get the Row and Col during FocusLost? if not, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the `oppositeComponent`. The weird thing is, if this listener is attached to the table, the documentation tells that the table should be the "source" component (because it is a FocusLost event and the component that lost the focus is the table itself).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html#getOppositeComponent%28%29

Comment: the oppositeComponent is a javax.swing.JViewport. not a JTable

Answer (score 0):

Could you just keep a record of row & column using

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);
```

So every time the use clicks update it, not just on focus events?

Comment: What kind of Listener should i use? currently i am using FocusListener.

Comment: I mean, what is the best way to share the row and column information from ListSelectionListener to FocusListener?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the data that was entered in the cell (without hitting return), then you don't need to do anything.  The updated information is contained within `TableModel` of the `JTable`.

Otherwise you can take a look at `.tableChanged()` and the associated `TableModelEvent`, which gives you the last row/column modified.  You could keep a variable that is always updated to the latest event row/column.  I guess that if you change a cell number without hitting return, it nonetheless registers as an event.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the condition below is always false because the source is always either a JTextField or a JComboBox.

This implies that the focusLost event is being generated when you begin editing a cell. So the question is why are you doing this? I think you need to state your actual requirement, because you attempted solution does not seem appropriate.

Comment: The functional requirement is this: